# Cannot set up the Android Cocos2d-x development environment on Windows 7

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, windows-7, cocos2d-x

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7) to set up an Android development environment. But when I  import folder `C:\cocos2d-x-2.2.0\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android` I see:

```
**** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project HelloCpp ****

 clean 

Cannot run program "": Launching failed
Error: Program "" is not found in PATH

PATH=[C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\cygwin64\bin\;D:\Projects\cpp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\;D:\Projects\cpp\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\]

**** Build Finished ****
```

What is wrong? What does Eclipse want to do. I am completely new to Android development and also Eclipse. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocos2d-x 2.2 then follow following steps:

1. Install cygwin as mention in your given turorial
   you should install the following software packages through cygwin

> autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g++, gcc4-core, gcc4-g++,
>   gdb, pcre, pcre-dev

1. Give the path of you **c:/cygwin/bin** in the environment variable
2. You have to also install CDT for your eclipse(If it is not and if you are using adt-bundle then need not to install)
3. You have to also download ndk-r8d/r8e or any one
4. Now Import your project in the eclipse
5. Now you go to your project properties and go to code analysis(in the C/C++ analysis)
   and select the `use project property` and then `unchecked the syntax and semantics error`
6. Now in your project open `build_native.sh` give the path of `ndk_rook` like this

   NDK_ROOT="D:\android-ndk-r8d"

Now you can run your project..........

Comment: `syntax and semantics error` was unchecked and `use project settings` was selected` but I still have the error. About CDT, I don't need it according to the tutorial, do I need it?

Comment: BTW I was trying to use cocos2dx-v3.0 alpha1. The setup steps for 2.2 and 3.0 alpha 1 are different?

Comment: Actually as I understand my main problem is Eclipse, as far as I could build .apk. Just I cannot run it form Eclipse. I need to setup Eclipse, but how? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I am not using alpha because it has a lot of changes and at the movement cocos2d-x2.2 is good

Comment: plz try to import templete of cocos2d-x

Comment: What does it mean to import template of cocos2d-x?

Comment: there is an temolete folder in the cocos2d-x in which it contain the project  D:\cocos2d-x-2.2\template